# QM course question about a two-level system with energy splitting coupled to a harmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, two-level-system

[image]

I am fine with part *a*, if I drop all the terms of the same and smaller magnitudes than $O(1/\eta)$ after expansion. For part *b* and *c*, although I don't understand why "only the second term is large" would imply "the two-level system must be in its ground state", I was hinted for the computation that I should treat $(\hat{a}+\hat{a}^\dagger)^2\hat{\sigma}_z$ as a tensor product and make use of the fact $\langle 0| \hat{\sigma}_z|0\rangle =-1$, leaving only the part of creation and annihilation, which still processes an infinite number of eigen-energies.

So I might end up with $\hat{H}_0'=\hbar\omega_0\left(\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}+1/2\right)-\hbar\Omega/2-\hbar g(\hat{a}+\hat{a}^\dagger)^2$? But I am not sure how this is realized in matrix representation, so that we don't obtain a scalar after doing $\langle 0| \hat{H}'|0\rangle$. Does it mean that I should consider $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_0'=\hbar\omega_0\left(\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}+1/2\right)\otimes I_2+\hbar\Omega/2\cdot I_{\infty}\otimes\hat{\sigma}_z+\hbar g(\hat{a}+\hat{a}^\dagger)^2\otimes \hat{\sigma}_z$? Then what should $|0\rangle$ become? $I_{\infty}\otimes (0,1)^\mathrm{T}$?

Comment: Well the 2-level is either up or down, right? Think about sigma z eigenstates

Comment: Regarding your final questions: yes, you have a space for the a operators and another for sigma. When you project the hamiltonian over sigma states you are coarse-graining it (or as goes the jargon "integrating out the spin degrees of freedom") in order to obtain an effective theory.